# Android image size

Tags: android

I have designed this screen:[image: Sample Screen]

I am testing it on redmi note3 phone. I have placed my images in mipmap-xxhdpi. All the icons are of size 144x144 . But these look very big. Should I move this to drawable folder. SHould I reduce the size of the images. I have read that icons should be of 144x144 for xxhdpi. How should I decide what should be the size of my image. How will it adjust to different screen densities?
Here's my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.LoginActivity"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/usr"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"/>

    <EditText
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email"
        android:hint="@string/pass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/pass"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border" />


    <Button
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/signin_color_orange"
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/password"
        android:text="Sign In" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@id/signin"
        android:id="@+id/oval_sep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/oval"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/left_sep"
        android:layout_below="@id/signin"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/oval_sep"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/border_color"/>
    <View
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/right_sep"
        android:layout_below="@id/signin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oval_sep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/border_color" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/or_text"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_sep"
        android:layout_below="@id/signin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textColor="@color/black_overlay"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/signup_txt"
        android:id="@+id/signup_txt"
        android:layout_below="@id/oval_sep" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/social_sep"
        android:layout_below="@id/signup_txt"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/signin_color_orange"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/google"
        android:layout_below="@id/signup_txt"
        android:background="@drawable/social_button_border"
        android:id="@+id/google"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/social_sep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/fb"
        android:layout_below="@id/signup_txt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/social_sep"
        android:background="@drawable/social_button_border_fb"
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <View

        android:id="@+id/btn_sep"
        android:layout_below="@id/fb"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_sep"
        android:id="@+id/lost_pswd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/account_border"
        android:text="@string/lost_pswd"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/account_border"
        android:text="@string/create_accnt"
        android:id="@+id/crt_accnt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lost_pswd"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `I have placed my images in mipmap-xxhdpi.` **Wrong**: You must use `drawable-xxhdpi`. Because mipmap is **only for the launcher icon**. You might want to read this [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the resolution that you are designing your PSD. There is no standard size for each pixel density. For example any image in xhdpi must be half the size of xxxhdpi, but they will display with the same size on corresponding devices. If your PSD is for xhdpi, then put your cropped icons in your xhdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create four dimension files and give the image the proper withs and heights accordingly

example:

```
android:width="@dimen/one"
```

Comment: ... four? so what about ldpi? or xxxhdpi? I'd say you need **six** files.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to put all the images that you are going to use in the app put them in drawable app. For different resolutions there are different drawable folders like drawable-mdpi(medium resolution- 48x48), drawable-hdpi(high resolution- 72x72), drawable-xhdpi(extra high resolution- 96x96), drawable-xxhdpi( extra extra high resolution- 144x144), drawable-xxxhdpi(extra extra extra high resolution- 192x192).

If you put every resolution images into their respective folders the app size may increase. So to avoid put high resolution image inside drawable-xxxhdpi and it is going to adjust to remaining resolution automatically. The best practice is create a image of size 192x192 and put it in drawable-xxxhdpi folder.